# How to read decimal and dates from Excel with C# and ADO.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am trying to read an Excel file in my ASP.NET application using the following piece of code (ADO.NET):

```
// Create OleDbCommand object and select data from worksheet Sheet1    
String query = String.Format("Select * From [{0}$]", sheetName);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, oledbConn);

// Create new OleDbDataAdapter
OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
oleda.SelectCommand = cmd;

//Fills Data to DataTable
oleda.Fill(dt);
```

The problem is that values in the data table are represented

**1)** For decimals either with a comma (3,14) or with a dot (3.14)

**2)** For dates with either the format 'DD/MM/YYYY' or'MM/DD/YYYY'

For the same Excel file depending on the locale settings server has.

Is there any way to read the data in a specific locale in order to get the correct values from the Excel file?

Comment: You are trying to parse the dates out of Excel? Not sure I understood the question entirely.

Comment: Yes, dates and decimals.

Comment: So for 1) you want `"3,14"` to be `decimal` and for 2) you want it to be `DateTime`?

Are these in separate columns or will you have to decide if it should be `decimal` or `DateTime`?

Comment: In different columns, I am trying to import data to my system from Excel. The DataTable reads from Excel either "3.14" or "3,14".

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the column with decimals, use the following to parse them: (`Decimal.Parse`)

```
string decimal1 = "3,14";
string decimal2 = "3.14";

decimal d1 = decimal.Parse(decimal1, new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "," });
decimal d2 = decimal.Parse(decimal2);
```

Note that with a `,` you need to use a custom `NumberFormatInfo` for it to parse right.

Then for your `DateTime` column:

```
string date1 = "14/03/2018";
string date2 = "03/14/2018";

DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date2, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Here you will want to specify the differnt formats for your dates.

---

**EDIT:**

To be more general about parsing an unknown `DateTime` format, you could try iterating through all the formats for your `CultureInfo` or multiple `CultureInfo` if you know there might be more than one. An example is below of how you could do this:

```
string dateTimeString = @"03/14/2018";

string[] possibleStandardFormats = new CultureInfo("en-US")
                                     .DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns();

DateTime? result = null;
foreach (string format in possibleStandardFormats) {
    if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString, out DateTime dateTime)) {
        // this format could work
        result = dateTime;
        break;
    }
}

if (result == null) {
    // no luck with any format
    // try one last parse
    if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString, out DateTime dateTime)) {
        // finally worked
        result = dateTime;
    }
    else {
        // no luck
    }
}
```

Here it may be more effective to try the general `DateTime.TryParse` first (shown at the end of this example), as it could save you the iterations through the other formats. Up to you how you want to handle this, but this example should handle the majority of the cases.

**EDIT 2:**

In order to get the standard `DateTime` formats, you can use the `CurrentCulture` which will help with your dates. In my previous edit, I hard coded `new CultureInfo("en-US")`, but the below is a bit more general.

```
string[] possibleStandardFormats = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)
                                            .DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns();
```

**EDIT 3:**
To expound a bit more on the previous parsing of decimals, first check if the string has a comma and then parse it according to the method I have listed above.

```
string decimal1 = "3,14";

if (decimal1.Contains(",")) {
    decimal d1 = decimal.Parse(decimal1, new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "," });
}
else {
    decimal d1 = decimal.Parse(decimal1);
}
```

**EDIT 4:**

To incorporate culture into parsing decimals, you can try the `Convert.ToDecimal` method. One of its parameters takes a `CultureInfo` where you can pass in your current culture as `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. For example below, I am using `de-de` (German) since that is a valid culture for `1.234,14`

```
string decimal1 = "1.234,14";
string decimal2 = "1,234.14";

decimal d1 = Convert.ToDecimal(decimal1, new CultureInfo("de-de"));
decimal d2 = Convert.ToDecimal(decimal2, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: I don't know the Format, it depends on the locale settings of the server.

Comment: @Dimitris see my edit. I expanded how to format an `unknown` format. It only handles the standard formats, but that will hopefully catch the majority of them for you

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but this will not work properly for me, because 05/06/2018 is valid for both formats  5 June and 6 May. So, the question is, where the culture of ado.net is specified and if I can modify this, in order to know the format I expect to get for decimals and dates

Comment: @Dimitris what do you have that you can determine the culture based on? Unfortunately without knowledge of that, there is really no way around this

Comment: @Dimitris would using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` be an option?

Comment: I will try this approach, but I am not very optimistic about it. I am trying to understand, when odata.Fill(dt) gives me 3,14 and when 3.14. but still I have no answer. If I know this I can handle the rest

Comment: @Dimitris not sure I understand the diiference between `3.14` and `3,14` since you can parse either case and end up with a `decimal` with a value of `3.14`? Also, `new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name).DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns();` will use the current culture name which should eliminate the guesswork of `MM/dd` vs `dd/MM` I edited my answer to include this.

Comment: The difference between 3,14 and 3.14 is that, if I get from ado.net 3,14 with en-us culture, the decimal.parse will return 314, or if I get 3.14 with gr-el  culture then decimal.parse will give me again 314

Comment: @Dimitris do you want `3.14` => `3.14` and `3,14` => `3.14`? (both cases evaluate to `3.14`)?

Comment: @Dimitris I think I understand it now. See my latest edit, basically check for a comma and parse the decimal accordingly since it does not depend on the culture. Unless there is an additional case I am missing?

Comment: thank you very much for your response but neither this will work. Because in the case I have decimal separator comma then the thousand separator will be dot. And if I have dot as decimal separator then the thousand will be comma. So, for parsing the decimals and the dates correctly, I must know or define somehow the culture of ado.net

Comment: @Dimitris any luck so far?

Comment: thank you so much for your interest. I didn't manage to do it. but I came up with a solution without testing it so far. I am thinking before reading the excel to insert a decimal value (e.g. 13,13) to a specific cell and then read this value. If  I have a dot for separator then I will use en-US locale else I will use el-GR.